# On defining a test Factory that will run a single browser test on the various browsers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, saucelabs

I am trying to concept out how to implement a Factory to test a test class on all browsers that I have defined.    Is there a better way to do this.  Can anyone suggest a basic improvement?

```
public class FactoryDataProviderTestBase extends MyTestBase 
{
  @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
  public FactoryDataProviderTestBase( SauceTestHelper helper, 
       Map<String,String> csvArgMap ) {
    super( helper,  csvArgMap );
  }

  @DataProvider( name = "factory" )
  static public Object[][] factoryDataProvider() {

    // do stuff here to initialize csvArgMap from csv file

    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.FirefoxLatest), argMap },
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.IE8), argMap },
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.IE9), argMap },
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.IE10), argMap },
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.IE11), argMap },
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.Safari7), argMap },
      new Object[] { new SauceTestHelper(browser.Chrome), argMap }
    };

  }
}
```

In the code above, TestNG should create multiple instances of the class FactoryDataProviderTestBase, one for each defined browser?

Comment: I am not familiar with TestNG but JUnit has a parameterized runner option that allows you to setup parameters before running a test. TestNG might have something similar. See if this answer helps your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604745/parameterized-selenium-tests-in-parallel-with-testng.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Selenium's Grid](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) for this.  Setup and configuration information can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)

Comment: I do use Selenium Grid, in the form of Sauce Labs grid.  Also, my question IS NOT about Selenium Grid configuration.