# Parameterized Selenium Tests in Parallel with TestNG

Tags: java, testng, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

First of all, sorry for my english, it's not so perfect :)

So I'm facing with the following problem: I'm trying to run parallel tests in different browsers using Selenium Grid and TestNg and I pass the parameters in the @BeforeTest method. My problem is that when every test get initialized, it seems that they will use the last test's parameters. So in this example when I run the test, it will open two Chrome, instead of one Firefox and one Chrome.
*(The browser.getDriver() method returns a RemoteWebDriver)*

**TestNG.xml:**

```
<suite thread-count="2" verbose="10" name="testSuite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="nameOfTheTestFirefox">
    <parameter name="platform" value="windows"/>
    <parameter name="browserVersion" value="32"/>
    <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="example.test.login.LoginOverlayTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- nameOfTheTestFirefox -->
  <test name="nameOfTheTestChrome">
    <parameter name="platform" value="windows"/>
    <parameter name="browserVersion" value="38"/>
    <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="example.test.login.LoginOverlayTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- nameOfTheTestChrome -->
</suite> <!-- testSuite -->
```

**The AbstractTest class:**

```
public class SeleniumTest {

    private static List<WebDriver> webDriverPool = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriver>());
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThread;
    public static BrowserSetup browser;

    @Parameters({ "browserName", "browserVersion", "platform"})
    @BeforeTest()
    public static void beforeTest(String browserName, @Optional("none") String browserVersion, String platform) throws WrongBrowserException, WrongPlatformException {

        final BrowserSetup browser = new BrowserSetup(browserName, browserVersion, platform);

        driverThread = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {

            @Override
            protected WebDriver initialValue() {
                final WebDriver webDriver = browser.getDriver();
                webDriverPool.add(webDriver);
                return webDriver;
            }

        };

    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driverThread.get();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public static void afterTest() {
        for (WebDriver driver : webDriverPool) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**And my example @Tests:**

```
@Test
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    System.out.println("START: test1");
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("END:  test1, title: " + driver.getTitle());
}

@Test
public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    System.out.println("START: test2");
    driver.get("http://amazon.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("END:  test2, title: " + driver.getTitle());
}

@Test
public void test3() throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    System.out.println("START: test3");
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("END:  test3, title: " + driver.getTitle());
}
```

So my question is how can I run the tests in parallel with the given parameters in separate threads?

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make the fields static.

```
private static List<WebDriver> webDriverPool = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriver>());
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThread;
public static BrowserSetup browser;
```

Answer (score 2):

beforeTest() and afterTest() shouldn't be static if you want to run it in parallel, or make it synchronized to have it thread safe. Also, you do not use declared variable:

```
public static BrowserSetup browser;
```

at all, or you missed something there since you also have:

```
final BrowserSetup browser = new BrowserSetup(browserName, browserVersion, platform);
```

inside beforeTest(...)

Comment: Yes I forgot to delete it, thank you :) I remove all the static things from my code and it works fine now :)