# How to run test suites parallel or serially in multiple browser using selenium grid

Tags: xml, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

How to run test suites parallel or serially in multiple browser using selenium grid. 
I have 3 xml files, one chrome.xml(contains all my test to be run in chrome), and one firefox.xml(contains all my test to be run in firefox) and testng.xml contains the both as suites.

> Chrome.xml

```
 <suite name="Chrome">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ww5.listener.Listener" />
</listeners>
<test name="v5">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <classes>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.version.version" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LoginTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LogoutTest" ></class>
   </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

> firefox.xml

```
<suite name="Firefox">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ww5.listener.Listener" />
</listeners>
<test name="v5">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
  <classes>
        <class name="ww5.testcases.version.version" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LoginTest" ></class> 
        <class name="ww5.testcases.loginSuite.LogoutTest" ></class>
   </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

> testng.xml

```
<suite name="My Project" parallel="tests">   
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="ww5.listener.Listener" />
</listeners>
  <suite-files>
     <suite-file path="./Chrome.xml" />
     <suite-file path="./firefox.xml" />
 </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Thanks in advanced, i am using page object model hence the reason for suite file for each browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your WebDriver thread safe.
2. Init your WebDriver in `@BeforeTest` and use the `quit()` in the `@AfterTest`.

You can find an example under one of my question: [Parameterized Selenium Tests in Parallel with TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604745/parameterized-selenium-tests-in-parallel-with-testng)

**Update:**

*How to make your WebDriver thread safe:*

```
  private List<WebDriver> webDriverPool = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriver>());
  private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThread;

  @BeforeTest()
  public void beforeTest() {
      //...
      this.driverThread   = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
        @Override
        protected WebDriver initialValue() {
          WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(...);
          webDriverPool.add(webDriver);
          return webDriver;
        }
      };
  }

  @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
  public void afterTest() {
    for (WebDriver driver : this.webDriverPool) {
      driver.quit();
    }
  }

  // Use this method instead of driver.get()
  public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.driverThread.get();
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for been stupid, but how to i make my webdriver thread safe

Comment: Check the link what I sent. You can see there :)

Comment: there a lot information on the link, could you direct me.

Comment: WebDriver webDriver = browser.getDriver(); ,  do you have a different class called browser?